# change Glide load images cache directory

Tags: android, android-glide

i want to change Glide load images cache directory from my app, To clean master fails to wipe the cache.i used

```
 builder.setDiskCache(new ExternalCacheDiskCacheFactory(context, "abbasali", cacheSize100MegaBytes * 5));
```

in my GlideModule but But it makes no effect.

Comment: does GlideModule properly configured and got initialized? meaning does does your call to setDiskCache get called?

Comment: now my images cache is in android/data/myPakacgeName/chache/abbasali/

Comment: Glide will use an existing cache in preference to a new one. So if you have already run your app prior to this change,there will be an internal cache that is used. To remove the internal cache, just clear your app cache settings from the Android App Settings menu.

Answer (score 3):

`Glide` doesn't support directly accessing the cache by design. `Cache` is a transparent storage, meaning you don't need to know about it. Also in `Glide` the caching is much more fine grained than just the `url` as key.

So the solution is to load normally and it will be loaded from the cache if it's there, otherwise downloaded and then loaded. Look into `.diskCacheStrategy()` for more control as to what gets cached.

```
Glide.with(context)
 .load(image_url)   
 .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
 .into(imageView);
```

If you use `DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE` (included in `ALL`) your original image will be stored in the phone and likely available when you need it offline. Cache will be always consulted first before going for the `network`.

here is a Sample code for loading image from `DiskCache`  using `Glide`

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/glidelibrary/TcFOy0tcxXA

Comment: Hi Rafsanahmad , this is my question on `Stack Overflow` `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51581231/images-disappear-when-scrolling-up-and-down-and-spaces-increase-between-images-u` . My problem is the images reload when I scroll up and down and I can't fix this problem .